# Qt Proxy with type of source object

Tags: qt, proxy, qt5

I have class, say `MyClass`, inherited from `QSqlRelationalTableModel` and I need to transpose it (change rows with columns).
[This](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Transpose_proxy_model) solution was found.
Is it possible to get *transposed object of type `MyClass`* after using the proxy? If not, are there any other ways to do it?

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I wanna use is like this:

```
MyClass* myObject = new MyClass(this, db);
TransposeProxyModel* trans = new TransposeProxyModel(this);
trans->setSourceModel(myObject);
ui->tableViewDb->setModel(trans);
ui->tableViewDb->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableViewDb));
```

It is necessary to paste object of MyClass (or QSqlRelationalTableModel) into QSqlRelationalDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited as per question clarification)

Why do you need to pass the source model into the `QSqlRelationalDelegate`? If you use the stock delegate then the delegate needs to operate on top of data that it visualizes (data from `TransposeProxyModel`).

If you have a custom subclass of `QSqlRelationalDelegate` and you want to access the source data from there for any reason, then you can pass `myObject` as a second argument to delegate constructor, or you can access it through `QModelIndex::model()` methods of the `index` passed to delegate's methods.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply! I need to get transposed table as object of MyClass class. I've added sample of using I want to achieve above.